# db-reverse-engineer plugin does not generate domain files

Tags: hibernate, grails, plugins

UPDATE: I tried changing the datasource from Oracle to Access (yes I know), and the plugin was able to generate the tables. So at least I've narrowed it down a little bit, still not sure whats causing this to fail.

When running the [db-reverse-engineer Grails plugin](http://grails-plugins.github.io/grails-db-reverse-engineer/), it does not generate any domain files, and exits saying it was successful (no errors).

I have tried all versions of the plugin, on a Grails 2.4.4 and a Grails 3.1.4 setup, on completely fresh applications. All the datasources I've tried are Oracle. I Have also made sure to configure it correctly by specifying the schema, and the specific tables I wanted. I've also fiddled with using hibernate 3/4 on the 2.4.4 test app. If I don't specify the schema or tables, the command takes a long time to execute (because of all the tables it can see), but still produces zero output. The plugin is definitely doing *something*.

Anyone have any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Below is some of the related code in one of my test apps.

(Grails version: 3.1.4, Groovy version: 2.4.6, JVM version: 1.7.0_80)

application.groovy

```
grails.plugin.reveng.includeTables = 
[
    'EXAMPLE_TABLE', 'EXAMPLE_TABLE2'
]
grails.plugin.reveng.defaultSchema = ['EXSCHEMA']
```

And here is a snippet from my application.yml

```
hibernate:
    cache:
        queries: false
        use_second_level_cache: true
        use_query_cache: false
        region.factory_class: 'org.hibernate.cache.ehcache.EhCacheRegionFactory'

dataSource:
    pooled: true
    jmxExport: true
    driverClassName: oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver
    dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle10gDialect
    username: REMOVED
    password: REMOVED

spring:
   freemarker:
      checkTemplateLocation: false    

environments:
    development:
        dataSource:
            url: jdbc:oracle:thin:@REMOVED:REMOVED:REMOVED
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I managed to get the plugin to work by NOT specifying the schema. If I just specify the tables I want it works as expected, but as soon as I add the line specifying the schema it generates nothing. No idea why, but hey at least I got it to work. If anyone has any ideas as to why, feel free to leave a comment!

Answer (score 0):

Are you running the commands from an IDE?

I used the plugin for a version 2.x app and had same issues as you & just restarting the IDE (GGTS) would allow the plugin to run once or twice but then I'd have to restart it again.

Also GGTS sometimes wouldn't refresh the /domain directory even though new domain classes had been generated.

Comment: For 2.4.4 I used the Grails CLI (CMD on windows), and for Grails 3.1.4 I used Intellij. I'll see if I still have a copy of GGTS somewhere on this PC...

Comment: I didn't see any changes with GGTS unfortunately, but thanks for giving me the idea to try it at least. I must be configuring something wrong somewhere...